# Dynamic routing static export makes it hard to route in S3 + Cloudfront [NextJS]

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using a dynamic routing template to manage nested paths.

I'm serving everything static with S3 Cloudfront and had to remove .html from the exported Next files to support the deployment environment chosen.

I'm finding it very difficult to resolve solutions/a.html because when I try to rename it it clashes with the folder name a.

In a way a.html should probably be index.html within the a/ folder, but that will cause issues with Cloudfront which only support index.html files for root files.

Is there a way to fix this or maybe update my out config - I was thinking I could use the exportPathMap to define the paths as needed.

```
/pages
   /solutions
      [...id].tsx
```

Out folder export (redacted):

```
└── solutions
   ├── a
   |  ├── b
   |  ├── b.html
   |  ├── c
   |  ├── c.html
   ├── a.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to flatten the structure of `solutions`. This solved my issues with `a.html` not being able to be renamed to `a` because of the `a/` folder.

Now that this was achieved all that was left was to change the `ContentType` to `text/html`. I achieved this using the `serverless-s3-sync` package which has a params prop.

```
└── solutions
   ├── a
   ├── a.html
   ├── b
   ├── b.html
   ├── c
   ├── c.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider `Lambda@Edge` at your cache behaviour on `origin-request` that is pointing to the actual file:

```
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const uri = request.uri;

  if (uri.endsWith('/')) {
    request.uri += 'index.html';
  } else if (!uri.includes('.')) {
    request.uri += '/index.html';
  }

  callback(null, request);
};
```

This should do the trick without the need to flatten the structure